# Minimal and latest way of triggering batch job in the world of Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have setup a batch job with Spring Boot 1.5.8 and relevant Spring Batch and Integration starters. I want to kick off the job using incoming file using file poller.

I have used Spring Integration in old days to trigger batch job with file poller. Is this still stands same ? Does Spring Batch itself has this very basic functionality or do I have to have Spring Integration involved as well ?

Even if Spring Integration is needed, can anybody point to Annotation based sample application doing the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good questions.   Let's answer each of them:

Is this still stands same ?  `Yes`

Does Spring Batch itself has this very basic functionality or do I have to have Spring Integration involved as well ? `No, you have to use Spring Integration`

Even if Spring Integration is needed, can anybody point to Annotation based sample application doing the same ? 
`We are in the midst of updating all the Batch docs to include annotation as well as XML based configurations.   Here is a doc that is in PR but will be merged in the next release that has the examples you are looking for:`
https://github.com/cppwfs/spring-batch/blob/1f7cada52aba95bcb23d06bc034b21fe1de0a7a5/spring-batch-docs/asciidoc/spring-batch-integration.adoc#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages

Comment: The answer and the document helped a lot. At the end of the batch job I get "org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.integrationFlow.channel#3'" error. Tried few things but did not work. Also, one weird problem, when I start the process, somehow SI remembers old file processed and kicks off the job with that one!